# Blowing up TNT in Minecraft classic

Tags: minecraft-classic-browser

How do I blow up boxes of TNT in minecraft classic?

I just tried playing on the website and tried minecraft-classic since it is free (yet outdated). Within the game one of the blocks I can use is TNT.

Tutorials mention redstone but I don't seem to have it. How can I blow up these boxes of TNT?

Comment: Just to let you know, Minecraft Classic is really outdated, and pretty much everything you read online nowadays will not apply to it.

Comment: i think you can with lava on ablocks lava survival

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't detonate TNT in Minecraft Classic. Redstone, and indeed exploding TNT, are features that were just not implemented at this point.

The block is there, but if I remember correctly, the functionality of activating it by punching was added in the Survival Test version, i.e. the version directly after the current Classic version. Redstone was also added at a later date (Alpha 1.0.1, [according to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Alpha)).